# SVG Horizontal Dashed Circle

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to create the following as an SVG:

[image: Desired SVG]

I.e. a circle with dashed horizontal lines.

This is the SVG code I have at the moment...generated by Adobe Illustrator:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="165px" height="165px" viewBox="0 0 165 165" enable-background="new 0 0 165 165" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 
  <circle fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="9" stroke-miterlimit="23" stroke-dasharray="1.0048,6.0288" cx="82.453" cy="82.563" r="75"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

But when I open in Chrome the lines seem to be very jagged and some lines are closer then others.

[image: Jagged lines in Chrome]

Is there a better way to produce this SVG or shall I simply use a PNG?

Comment: Not everyone uses Chrome. Your code looks fine on my iPad, for example. If you want the best possible quality, consistent across browsers, and don't care about the scaleability of an SVG, then yeah sure, use a bitmap.

Comment: Thanks @Jongware I realised this after I posted it! I'll leave it open though in case someone comes up with a more stable way of producing the SVG

Comment: ... my point is, I don't think it's the SVG to blame - it's the *renderer*. Suppose you find a way that makes it look great on Chrome and you are personally very happy with that. What if someone using a different renderer then complains it looks bad on his screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a different approach to produce the same appearance which should be more stable across renderers, by using actual line segments rather than very short stroke dashes.

I've used `<defs>` and `<use>` to keep the repetition sane — I define four axis-aligned lines around a center and then rotate it by a quarter-circle of even steps. (I changed the scale a bit for the sake of round numbers in my example.)

Note that if zoomed in it will be slightly different: in the original, each dash will be slightly wedge-shaped (due to the curve of the circle), whereas here they will have a constant width since they are just plain line segments.

```html
<svg width="160px" height="160px" viewBox="0 0 160 160">
  <defs>
    <g id="lines" style="stroke: black;">
      <line x1=" 71" x2=" 79" />
      <line x1="-71" x2="-79" />
      <line y1=" 71" y2=" 79" />
      <line y1="-71" y2="-79" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(80 80)">
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate( 0)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate( 5)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(10)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(15)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(20)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(25)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(30)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(35)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(40)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(45)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(50)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(55)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(60)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(65)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(70)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(75)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(80)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#lines" transform="rotate(85)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This is a SVG-in-HTML fragment — if using it as a standalone SVG document don't forget to put the `xmlns` back in.

Comment: Thanks @kevin-reid this is a great suggestion and seems to make more sense than what I was doing. Just to note I was not using wedges in the example so this is perfect :) It renders a tiny bit better but I think is generally clearer!

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I didn't bother to count them :) Mine has 72 ticks since it goes around the circle in 5-degree steps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach with the same tick count and tick size.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="165px" height="165px" viewBox="0 0 165 165">
  <g transform="translate(82.453 82.563)">
    <g id="t32">
      <g id="t16">
        <g id="t8">
          <g id="t4">
            <g id="t3">
              <rect x="70.5" y="-0.5024" width="9" height="1.0048" id="t"/>
              <use xlink:href="#t" transform="rotate(5.37)"/>
              <use xlink:href="#t" transform="rotate(10.75)"/>
            </g>
            <use xlink:href="#t" transform="rotate(16.12)"/>
          </g>
          <use xlink:href="#t4" transform="rotate(21.49)"/>
        </g>
        <use xlink:href="#t8" transform="rotate(42.99)"/>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#t16" transform="rotate(85.97)"/>
    </g>
    <use xlink:href="#t32" transform="rotate(171.94)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#t3" transform="rotate(343.88)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```